# Simple Abstract data type linked list

Tags: c++, class, generics, data-structures, linked-list

my classes

```
class Product
{
...
};

class Perishable : public : Product
{
 public:
 int getday();

};
```

I want to contain a collection of both perishable and product object together and hope to do it by means of a linked list.

Usually for linked list we have something like

```
class linkedlist
{
           struct List
           {
             int item;
             ListNode* next; 
           }
          //.... all the functions
};
```

but i have a problem here since the data i want to store in item  is not an int but either a Product or a Perishable, how do i implement it as a linked list?

Comment: Do you really need your own linked list? Just use `std::vector<Product*>` from STL.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `Product*` as an item in the linked list. You should add `virtual` methods to the base class `Product` which will be dispatched to the appropriate method during run time depending on the actual type of object pointed by this pointer.

Comment: I dont think this would be appropriate as Generic Programming (courtsey: Alex Stepanov) is meant to do that and STL is based on Templates which does not have OO stuff that you mentioned above because there are no virtual destructors. Now I feel any data structure problem in C++ is more of Generic Programming stuff as opposed to Object Oriented.

Answer (score 1):

You need Templates. Templates in C++ support generic programming. After declaring template  before your class LinkedList you can replace your int item with a T item where T is the place holder and will be substituted for an appropriate data type (custom or primitive) depending upon how you instantiate your object.